# Page numbering left and right

Tags: page-numbering

What is the easiest way, to have a page numbering in the documentclass article (`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}`) on the left/right?

Comment: Top or bottom? On the outer side of the page

Comment: bottom at the outer side

Comment: Any header/footer, or only the page numbers?

Comment: Any package or do you already employ one for header/footer?

Comment: just the page numbers I don't have any header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the simplest consists in redefining the  `plain` page style with `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`. Add this to you preamble:

```
\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}%
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Explanation of the code: the 3 optional arguments of `\setfoot` (in brackets) are for the  left, centre and right parts of the footer on even pages, the 3 mandatory arguments for the same parts of the footer on odd pages.

*Note*: If you already load `titlesec`, do not load `titleps`, just load titlesec with option `[pagestyles]`.

Answer (score 1):

I like `scrlayer-scrpage` from KOMA-script. With it the following does what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{} % define font style for page head foot
\clearpairofpagestyles % remove the defaults
\ofoot{\pagemark} % put the page number in the outer footer

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

Or an alternative could be `fancyhdr` for which you could use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} % no line between document and header
\fancyhead{} % clear header
\fancyfoot{} % clear footer
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % page at left on even and right on odd pages

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```